# check if all inputs are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 2 buttons and 2 inputs. The "buy"-button should only fire its default function when both inputs are checked. If not it should mark them with a red border. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $('.checkedterms:checked').length == $('.checkedterms').length
 $("#upsellyes").click(function(e) {
  $(".checkedterms").change(function(){
   if (!$('.checkedterms:checked').length == $('.checkedterms').length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#terms-required").addClass('invalid');
   } 
   else {
    $("#terms-required").removeClass('invalid');
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="terms-required">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkedterms" name="terms" id="terms" style="position: absolute;"><label for="terms" class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block!important;font-weight:normal!important;margin-left: 25px;">I have read <a href="#" >Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a>.<span class="required">*</span></label><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkedterms" name="terms" id="terms" style="position: absolute;"><label for="terms" class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block!important;font-weight:normal!important;margin-left: 25px;">I have read <a href="#" >Widerrufsbelehrung</a>.<span class="required">*</span></label><br />
</div><br>
<a href="#" id="upsellyes">buy</a><br><br>
<a href="#">no thanks</a>
```

Comment: should this line be in an if statement? $('.checkedterms:checked').length == $('.checkedterms').length

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong here. In your `click` handler you are adding a `changed` handler to `checkterms`. That doesn't make any sense. That function won't run until the value changes, and that certainly isn't what you intended

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here:

- You've got an equality check at the start of the code which does nothing.
- You've nested the `change` handler on the checkboxes within the `click` handler of the button; remove it.
- Unrelated to the issue, but you are using duplicate `id` attributes. They need to be unique within the DOM.
- Your logic is backwards. You state that you want the red border to only appear when both checkboxes *are not checked* when the 'Buy' button is clicked.

You can also make the logic more succinct by caching the checkbox selector and using `toggleClass()`. Something like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#upsellyes").click(function(e) {
    var $terms = $('.checkedterms');
    $("#terms-required").toggleClass('invalid', $terms.length != $terms.filter(':checked').length);
  });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.checkedterms {
  position: absolute;
}

label {
  display: inline-block!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="terms-required">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkedterms" name="terms" />
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox">
    I have read <a href="#">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a>.
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkedterms" name="terms" />
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox">
    I have read <a href="#" >Widerrufsbelehrung</a>.
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </label><br />
</div><br />

<a href="#" id="upsellyes">buy</a><br><br>
<a href="#">no thanks</a>
```

Finally note the use of a separate stylesheet. Inline styling is a bad idea and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Maybe usefull to include this in your answer. Using duplicate IDs is also a bad idea. :)

Comment: some browsers don't render `border` style to checkbox, use `outline` instead.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
$(".checkedterms").change(function(){ //remove
    //keep the code that's currently here
}); //remove
```

leaving you with

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.checkedterms:checked').length == $('.checkedterms').length
    $("#upsellyes").click(function(e) {
        if ($('.checkedterms:checked').length != $('.checkedterms').length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#terms-required").addClass('invalid');
        } 
        else {
            $("#terms-required").removeClass('invalid');
        }
    });
});
```

the code wasn't running because you were setting an event listener on the checkboxes inside the event listener on the button. what was happening is that when you clicked the button, javascript would set an event listener on the checkboxes that fires when their state changes

Comment: That actually still doesn't work because the `if` expression isn't right. Remove the leading `!` and use `!=`. Otherwise it'll always be false

Comment: once i spotted the error, i didn't really inspect the rest of the code more closely, if there are other issues with the code rory's answer is probably more detailed and helpful

Comment: @MattBurland yeah as i mentioned in the comment, i didn't inspect the rest of the code after seeing the faulty event listener, i'll make the edit

Answer (score -2):

You need an if statement at line 2 and one more '='

```
if ($('.checkedterms:checked').length === $('.checkedterms').length) {
 ....
}
```

and you should put an eventListener each input change

Comment: There's several other problems and the number of `=` signs in this case won't make a difference